# Deleting not needed bundles from Symfony 2?

Tags: symfony, bundle

Is possible to delete bundles not needed in order to keep the project clean? I'm using Symfony2 with propel to build a RESTful interface. Don't need:

- **Twig**
- **Doctrine2** (i prefer Propel instead)
- **Assetic** (without Twig assetic does not make sense, correct me if i'm wrong)
- **Security** (no need to model roles)

I can't find any how-to in order to remove uneeded bundles. Any help is much appreciated.

**EDIT**: monlog is the logger, not mongodb. Need it!

About `deps.lock` file: it can be removed after removing bundles, than issue:

```
php bin/vendors update
```

and i should be recreated. It maintains the git version id checked out, for each bundle.

Comment: Monolog has nothing to do with mongodb, it is a logger library.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Sure.  Remove them from `AppKernel` then delete from the file system if you want.  You could even edit the `deps` file to keep them from coming back.  Twig and Assetic are independent.  You could use the Assetic bundle with straight PHP.

Comment: What about deps.lock? I can find some lines referring to deleted items.

Comment: Sure.  Blow those lines away as well.

Answer (score 3):

In case anyone else runs into this issue, you can follow the instructions in the Symfony2 docs to remove the Acme Bundle: http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/cookbook/bundles/remove.html

The proccess is like this:

1. **delete** /src/Test/BlogBundle directory
2. change /app/config/routing.yml file to **remove the bundle routes**
3. **Unregister** your bundle from /app/AppKernel.php
4. **clear cache** (either by deleting cache/{$env} or console cache:clear)